# Data profiling in MongoDB when UI loaded

Tags: mongodb

How to measure performance when my UI starst loading? The backend is MongoDB and am new to this DB. Using `system.profile`, how we will find the execution time of loading the UI? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: If I load my production environment, it will take time to load.. So I want to know how much time it will take using profiler in mongodb